# How to update some data in a Listview without using notifyDataSetChanged()?

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I'm trying to create a `ListView` with a list of downloading tasks.

The downloading tasks are managed in a `Service` (DownloadService). Everytime a chunk of data is received, the task sends the progress via a `Broadcast`, received by the `Fragment` containing the `ListView` (SavedShowListFragment). On receiving the `Broadcast` message, the  SavedShowListFragment updates the progress of the downloading tasks in the adapter and triggers `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Every row in the list contains a `ProgressBar`, a `TextView` for the title of the file being downloaded and one for the numeric value of the progress, and a `Button` to pause/resume the download or play the saved show when the download is finished.

The problem is that the pause/resume/play `Button` is often not responsive (`onClick()` is not called), and I think that's because the whole list is updated very frequently with `notifyDataSetChanged()` (every time a chunk of data, i.e. 1024 bytes is received, which can be many times per second, especially when there are several downloading tasks running).

I guess I could increase the size of the data chunk in the downloading tasks, but I really think my method is not optimal at all!

Could calling very frequently `notifyDataSetChanged()` make the `ListView` UI unresponsive?

Is there any way to update only some `Views` in the `ListView` rows, i.e. in my case the `ProgressBar` and the `TextView` with the numeric value of the progress, without calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, which updates the whole list?

To update the progress of the downloading tasks in the `ListView`, is there any better option than "getChunk/sendBroadcast/updateData/notifyDataSetChanged"?

Below are the relevant parts of my code.

**Download task in download service**

```
public class DownloadService extends Service {

    //...

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<SavedShow, Void, Map<String, Object>> {

        //...

        @Override
        protected Map<String, Object> doInBackground(SavedShow... params) { 

            //...

            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int x = 0;

            while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {

                if(!this.isCancelled()){
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, x);
                    downloaded += x;

                    MyApplication.dbHelper.updateSavedShowProgress(savedShow.getId(), downloaded);

                    Intent intent_progress = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_PROGRESS);
                    intent_progress.putExtra(KEY_SAVEDSHOW_ID, savedShow.getId());
                    intent_progress.putExtra(KEY_PROGRESS, downloaded );
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(DownloadService.this).sendBroadcast(intent_progress);         
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }

            //...
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

**SavedShowListFragment**

```
public class SavedShowListFragment extends Fragment {   

    //...

    @Override
    public void onResume() {         
        super.onResume();

        mAdapter = new SavedShowAdapter(getActivity(), MyApplication.dbHelper.getSavedShowList());

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //...
    }


    private ServiceConnection mDownloadServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            // Get service instance

            DownloadServiceBinder binder = (DownloadServiceBinder) service;
            mDownloadService = binder.getService();

            // Set service to adapter, to 'bind' adapter to the service

            mAdapter.setDownloadService(mDownloadService);

            //...
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {

            // Remove service from adapter, to 'unbind' adapter to the service

            mAdapter.setDownloadService(null);
        }
    };


    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            if(action.equals(DownloadService.ACTION_UPDATE_PROGRESS)){  
                mAdapter.updateItemProgress(intent.getLongExtra(DownloadService.KEY_SAVEDSHOW_ID, -1),
                        intent.getLongExtra(DownloadService.KEY_PROGRESS, -1));
            }

            //...
        }
    };

    //...

}
```

**SavedShowAdapter**

```
public class SavedShowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SavedShow> { 

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    private List<Long> mSavedShowIdList; // list to find faster the position of the item in updateProgress

    private DownloadService mDownloadService;

    private Context mContext;

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView status;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        DownloadStateButton downloadStateBtn;
    }

    public static enum CancelReason{ PAUSE, DELETE };

    public SavedShowAdapter(Context context, List<SavedShow> savedShowList) {
        super(context, 0, savedShowList);       
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE ); 

        mContext = context;

        mSavedShowIdList = new ArrayList<Long>();

        for(SavedShow savedShow : savedShowList){
            mSavedShowIdList.add(savedShow.getId());
        }
    }

    public void updateItemProgress(long savedShowId, long progress){
        getItem(mSavedShowIdList.indexOf(savedShowId)).setProgress(progress);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateItemFileSize(long savedShowId, int fileSize){
        getItem(mSavedShowIdList.indexOf(savedShowId)).setFileSize(fileSize);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void updateItemState(long savedShowId, int state_ind, String msg){

        SavedShow.State state = SavedShow.State.values()[state_ind];

        getItem(mSavedShowIdList.indexOf(savedShowId)).setState(state);

        if(state==State.ERROR){
            getItem(mSavedShowIdList.indexOf(savedShowId)).setError(msg);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteItem(long savedShowId){
        remove(getItem((mSavedShowIdList.indexOf(savedShowId))));       
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setDownloadService(DownloadService downloadService){
        mDownloadService = downloadService;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {

            v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_show_list_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.status = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.status);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            holder.downloadStateBtn = (DownloadStateButton)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_download_state);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());

        Integer fileSize = getItem(position).getFileSize();
        Long progress = getItem(position).getProgress();
        if(progress != null && fileSize != null){
            holder.progressBar.setMax(fileSize);

            holder.progressBar.setProgress(progress.intValue());

            holder.status.setText(Utils.humanReadableByteCount(progress) + " / " +
                    Utils.humanReadableByteCount(fileSize));
        }

        holder.downloadStateBtn.setTag(position);

        SavedShow.State state = getItem(position).getState();

        /* set the button state */

        //...

        /* set buton onclicklistener */

        holder.downloadStateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int position = (Integer) v.getTag();

                SavedShow.State state = getItem(position).getState();

                if(state==SavedShow.State.DOWNLOADING){

                    getItem(position).setState(SavedShow.State.WAIT_PAUSE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    mDownloadService.cancelDownLoad(getItem(position).getId(), CancelReason.PAUSE);

                }
                else if(state==SavedShow.State.PAUSED || state==SavedShow.State.ERROR){                 

                    getItem(position).setState(SavedShow.State.WAIT_DOWNLOAD);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    mDownloadService.downLoadFile(getItem(position).getId());

                }
                if(state==SavedShow.State.DOWNLOADED){

                    /* play file */
                }

            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: (I am no expert , just a student) It is my opinion that progressBar.setProgress will be enough to update the List , am i wrong ? ... does this link help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200299/adding-a-progressbar-to-a-listview-onclick-called-a-single-time

Comment: My issue is not about how to set the progress, but how to update only some views in the ListView's row. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, your problem is notifyDataSetChanged will be called multiple times within 1 seconds. I have not idea how to update ListView UI without using notifyDataSetChanged but in this case, I would called notifyDataSetChanged for every 4 ~ 6 seconds instead of every moments when data is changed.

Comment: @edisonthk yes I can do this, but a progress bar updated every 4-6s is not very nice! That's probably what I'll do if I can't find any other solution though...

Comment: @jul It is not necessary must be 4-6s. Let's say downloading process update every 2ms, it will be very heavy to UI thread to keep updating everytime service is updated. To overcome this problems, I will make UI thread update every 100ms or 500ms instead of 2ms and 500ms is fast enough for human.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Of course, As **pjco** stated, do not update at that speed. I would recommend sending broadcasts at intervals. Better yet, have a container for the data such as progress and update every interval by polling.

However, I think it is a good thing as well to update the listview at times without `notifyDataSetChanged`. Actually this is most useful when the application has a higher update frequency. Remember: I am not saying that your update-triggering mechanism is correct.

---

**Solution**

Basically, you will want to update a particular position without `notifyDataSetChanged`. In the following example, I have assumed the following:

1. Your listview is called mListView.
2. You only want to update the progress
3. Your progress bar in your convertView has the id `R.id.progress`

---

```
public boolean updateListView(int position, int newProgress) {
    int first = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int last = mListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
    if(position < first || position > last) {
        //just update your DataSet
        //the next time getView is called
        //the ui is updated automatically
        return false;
    }
    else {
        View convertView = mListView.getChildAt(position - first);
        //this is the convertView that you previously returned in getView
        //just fix it (for example:)
        ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        bar.setProgress(newProgress);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

**Notes**

This example of course is not complete. You can probably use the following sequence:

1. Update your Data (when you receive new progress)
2. Call `updateListView(int position)` that should use the same code but update using your dataset and without the parameter.

In addition, I just noticed that you have some code posted. Since you are using a Holder, you can simply get the holder inside the function. I will not update the code (I think it is self-explanatory).

Lastly, just to emphasize, change your whole code for triggering progress updates. A fast way would be to alter your Service: Wrap the code that sends the broadcast with an if statement which checks whether the last update had been more than a second or half second ago and whether the download has finished (no need to check finished but make sure to send update when finished):

In your download service

```
private static final long INTERVAL_BROADCAST = 800;
private long lastUpdate = 0;
```

Now in doInBackground, wrap the intent sending with an if statement

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdate > INTERVAL_BROADCAST) {
    lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent intent_progress = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE_PROGRESS);
    intent_progress.putExtra(KEY_SAVEDSHOW_ID, savedShow.getId());
    intent_progress.putExtra(KEY_PROGRESS, downloaded );
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(DownloadService.this).sendBroadcast(intent_progress);
}
```

Comment: Are we implementing our own `notifyDataSetChanged()` this way?
check the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12234498/609782
because even `notifyDataSetChanged()` calls `getView()` on items visible only.

Comment: @Darpan `notifyDataSetChanged()` calls getView() on visible items only; true. But please be aware that it destroys all the available views and passes null convertViews to the getView(). In other words, the visible views are recreated.

Comment: That's what I said too, but I get your point. Difference lies in re-creating 'all' views and 'updating' only 'one' view like you did with your code. Good one.

Answer (score 9):

### The short answer: dont update the UI based on data speeds

Unless you are writing a speed test style app, there is no user benefit to updating this way.

`ListView` is ***very well optimized***, (as you seem to already know because you are using the ViewHolder pattern).

Have you tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` every 1 second?

Every 1024 bytes is ***ridiculously fast***.  If someone is downloading at 8Mbps that could be updating ***over 1000 times a second*** and this could definitely cause an ANR.

Rather than update progress based on amount downloaded, you should poll the amount at an interval that does not cause UI blocking.

Anyways, in order to help avoid blocking the UI thread you could post updates to a `Handler`.

Play around with the value for `sleep` to be sure you are not updating too often.  You could try going as low as **200ms** but I wouldn't go below **500ms** to be sure.  The exact value depends on the devices you are targeting and number of items that will need layout passes.

*NOTE: this is just one way to do this, there are many ways to accomplish looping like this.*

```
private static final int UPDATE_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 666;

Handler myHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case UPDATE_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}



private void runUpdateThread() { 
    new Thread(
     new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             while ( MyFragment.this.getIsDownloading() )
             {
                  try 
                  {    
                      Thread.sleep(1000); // Sleep for 1 second

                      MyFragment.this.myHandler
                          .obtainMessage(UPDATE_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS)
                          .sendToTarget();
                  } 
                  catch (InterruptedException e) 
                  {
                      Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                  }
             }

         }
     } ).start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although its not an answer to your question but one optimization that can be done in your `getView()` method is this, Instead of creating and setting click listener every time like this:

```
holder.downloadStateBtn.setTag(position); 
holder.downloadStateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            int position = (Integer) v.getTag(); 
             // your current normal click handling
        }
    });
```

You can just create it once as class variable and set it while creating row's `View`:

```
final OnClickListener btnListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        // your normal click handling code goes here
    }
}
```

and then in `getView()`:

```
 if (v == null) {
        v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_show_list_item, parent, false);
        // your ViewHolder stuff here 
        holder.downloadStateBtn.setOnClickListener(btnClickListener);//<<<<<
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
```

oh and don't forget to set tag on this button in `getView()` as you are already doing:

```
holder.downloadStateBtn.setTag(position);
```