# Android get progress of http POST send and receive response

Tags: android, post, android-asynctask, progress

I need to execute HTTP Post request in Android, and show separate progress of sending request body and downloading response. This must be a determinate progress.
Request body is JSON. One of it's attributes values is Base64 encoded String that represents image.
The server response is also a JSON, containing Base64 encoded image.
I need to show determinate progress bar for uploading request. Once it is sent but response isn't available yet - show indeterminate progress bar. Once response is ready - show determinate progress of downloading.
I used to use RETROFIT REST client for networking. But now it seems that RETROFIT can't help...

I'm looking towards using AsyncTask. But not sure if it is possible to get progress of POST response downloading.

Comment: Showing a response progressbar is often not possible as many servers don't provide a content length.

Comment: This one does. It's a client's back-end server. And they do provide content length of the response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875838/download-multiple-files-with-a-progress-bar-in-listview-android  see accepted ans at the link

Comment: Robert that is a link to great code. But a little overkill for now.

Comment: If you have the content length then a progress bar is easily implemented as you read the response from the inputstream in a loop.