# Android - Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I wrote a simple class extending `LinearLayout`, that implements a `ProgressBar` and a `TextView`. I'm able to set the progress of the bar from the `MainActivity` calling the method `_setProgress(int progr)_`. Now I want to add this "`CustomView`" as an item of a `ListView`, but I also need a way to simply update the progress at any time: How can I do these 2 things?

Comment: Have a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875838/download-multiple-files-with-a-progress-bar-in-listview-android

Comment: Use it in the list adapter class, for the progress update the easiest way is to keep the references of whatever you need to update later.

Comment: @Chris thanks, but there is another problem: in my class I have also a media player that plays or stops when clicking on the layout

Comment: The approach in the linked question should still work.  If not, post the code for how you've implemented it and detail the problem you're experiencing.