# Adding new task to intent service

Tags: android, intentservice

I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238868/8361923) to download multiple images and showing individual progress

but the problem is **how can I add new images to be downloaded** as the code adds file to be downloaded to intent before `startService(intent);`  if any other files  is added then where to handle that logic?

Comment: intent services queues up work automatically, just startService twice

Comment: @TimCastelijns It seems I am able to add tasks but only when its not already executing tasks like after on is finished then  only  starting intent works ... I want to add new tasks even when its executing a task

Comment: yeah that's not possible. As I said work is queued up, meaning it does one job after another

Comment: @TimCastelijns any other way or combination for getting similar result .. having multiple download lists with add ability and progress bar