# Download Manager with recycler view or list view

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    rel_showProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    float totalMb = (float) totalBytesDownloaded / (1024 * 1024);
                                    String size = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", totalMb);

                                    txt_progress.setText(msg);
                                    String tempSize = size + " MB";
                                    txt_fileSize.setText(tempSize);

                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                        progressBar.setProgress((int) finalProgressPercent, true);
                                    } else progressBar.setProgress((int) finalProgressPercent);

                                }
                            });
```

I am using this code and show download progress in a activity. but the problem is when i do multiple downloads then it overlaps. so i want to set downloads on recycler view or listview. but i am not able to figure it out that how can i set progress on recycler view progress bar. because recycler or listview take data from the arraylist or any other. so how can i set dynamic data on it.

Comment: you can update arraylist data as progress updates

Comment: how can do it dynamically, means it will take data for recyclerview as static

Comment: if i update arraylist each time then it will add data every time on call of new thread and not able to know position of arraylist for insertion of data.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875838/download-multiple-files-with-a-progress-bar-in-listview-android

Comment: it is difficult to understand because i have not used this code before @VivekMishra

Comment: Try according to that code and ask if you face problem