# switching between sets of icons in android gridview

Tags: android, gridview, notifydatasetchanged

I am new to android development. In my android `activity` I have a `GridView` and a `Button`. The `GridView adapter` class is displaying a set of icons in the `GridView`. What I want is, if the `Button` in the activity is clicked, the set of icons in the `GridView` should be replaced with another set of icons. And every `Button` click in the activity should switch the two sets of icons in the `GridView`. 
So, how to do this using `notifyDatasetChanged()`? Please Help.

`GridView Adapter` class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        boolean imageSetChange = false;

        // set 1
        public Integer[] mThumbPics = {
                  R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2,
                    R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4,
                    R.drawable.pic5, R.drawable.pic6,
                    R.drawable.pic7, R.drawable.pic8,
                    R.drawable.pic9, R.drawable.pic10,
                    R.drawable.pic11, R.drawable.pic12,
                    R.drawable.pic13, R.drawable.pic14,
                    R.drawable.pic15, R.drawable.pic16,
                    R.drawable.pic17, R.drawable.pic18,
                    R.drawable.pic19, R.drawable.pic20,
                    R.drawable.pic21

        };
        //set 2
        public Integer[] mThumbEng = {
                R.drawable.eng_pic1, R.drawable.eng_pic2,
                R.drawable.eng_pic3, R.drawable.eng_pic4,
                R.drawable.eng_pic5, R.drawable.eng_pic6,
                R.drawable.eng_pic7, R.drawable.eng_pic8,
                R.drawable.eng_pic9, R.drawable.eng_pic10,
                R.drawable.eng_pic11, R.drawable.eng_pic12,
                R.drawable.eng_pic13, R.drawable.eng_pic14,
                R.drawable.eng_pic15, R.drawable.eng_pic16,
                R.drawable.eng_pic17, R.drawable.eng_pic18,
                R.drawable.eng_pic19, R.drawable.eng_pic20,
                R.drawable.eng_pic21
               };

        private Context mContext;
        View MyView;
        ImageView imageView;

        public CustomAdapter(Context c){
            mContext = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mThumbEng.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mThumbEng[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(imageSetChange==false)
            {if(convertView == null){

                    LayoutInflater li=((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                    MyView=li.inflate(R.layout.menuitem, null);

                    }
                    else{
                        MyView=(View)convertView;
                    }
                imageView =(ImageView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                imageView.setImageResource(mThumbEng[position]);

                       return MyView;
                       }
            else{

                if(convertView == null){

                    LayoutInflater li=((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                    MyView=li.inflate(R.layout.menuitem, null);

                    }
                    else{
                        MyView=(View)convertView;
                    }
                imageView =(ImageView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                imageView.setImageResource(mThumbUrdu[position]);

                       return MyView;


            }


        }   

        /** public void changeImages(boolean change){
            this.imageSetChange  = change;

            cda.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    **/

}
```

Button onclick listener:

```
Button lang_change_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        lang_change_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //cda.changeImages(true);


            }
        });
```

Comment: Where are you calling the notifyDataSetchanged() ? 
You should call it after making the necessary changes, in your case it should be inside onClick if thats where you are making your necessary changes

Comment: How will I replace the two sets of icons on calling notifyDataSetchanged() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025841/how-to-update-some-data-in-a-listview-without-using-notifydatasetchanged might help I believe..